Why my realisation of UDP hole punching doesn't work?
I decided to make my own implementation of udp hole punching technology in C# to bypass NAT, but the problem is that for some reason I cannot receive the transmitted message. How I imagine this technology works:

There are clients A and B who need to establish a connection, a STUN server and a coordination server. In my case, instead of the coordination server, I am currently entering addresses manually

A sends a request to receive its external ip and port to the STUN server.

After receiving, it holds the UdpClient port, sending and receiving any information through this UdpClient in the background. In my case, it's just constantly getting an external endpoint.

Next, A sends information about its endpoint to the coordination server with a request to receive an external endpoint from user B.

Then B receives its external endpoint via the STUN protocol and also drives traffic through its UdpClient in the background

B begins to bombard user A with connection requests in the interval between repetitions of step 4, after which he waits N seconds for a response from A. If the answer has not come, then we stop accepting answers

B sends a request to the coordination server to connect to A, specifying its external endpoint

A receives an external endpoint B and also throws requests at user B

At some point, the packet sent by user A will get into the "window" waiting for receiving responses and the session will be established.

After connection establishing, we periodically drive traffic through the established "channel" to maintain it


Well, I stopped at point 8 and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong? The packets just don't reach B even with the Windows firewall turned off.
The only thing I had to write my own implementation was an extension of the existing udp client in C#, since the default one does not support canceling the request waiting without closing the client
For the test, I send requests from devices from the same wi-fi network.
Here is my shortened sender code:
enum CommandType
{
    SetValue,
    ResetValue
}

record Command<T>(CommandType Type,T? Value=null) where T:class;

//UI code(I use MAUI and sending requests from smartphone)...
// This is part, where execute logic for sending
new Thread(() => {
    while (true)
    {
        isSending = false;
        Task<IPEndPoint> endpoint_task=client.GetForeignIP();
        endpoint_task.Wait();
        var endpoint=endpoint_task.Result;
        //sending comand by button click
        if (send_test_command != null)
        {
            client.Udp.Send(send_test_command.Value,CurrentEndpoint);
            isSending = true;
        }
        //displaying results to interface...
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}).Start();

Here is the "server" code:
using STUN;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Free2P;
namespace P2PConsoleTest;
internal class Program
{
    static IPEndPoint? companion_endpoint =null;
    static void LaunchPortHolding(STUNClient client)
    {
        ReusableUdpClient udp = client.Udp;
        IPEndPoint selfEndpoint = udp.self_local_endpoint;
        int length = RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(14000,30000);
        byte[] debug = RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(length);
        CancellationTokenSource src = new();
        
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            IPEndPoint? remote=null;
            while (true)
            {
                var task1=client.GetForeignIP();
                task1.Wait();
                if (companion_endpoint!=null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Trying to connect with {companion_endpoint}...");
                    udp.Send(debug, companion_endpoint);
                    try
                    {
                        byte[] result=udp.Receive(3000,ref remote);
                        Console.WriteLine("Connection successfully!");
                        string msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(result);
                        Console.WriteLine(msg);
                        
                    }
                    catch (OperationCanceledException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Didn't connect!");
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }
    
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        CancellationTokenSource src = new();
        WaitHandle waiter = src.Token.WaitHandle;
        using STUNClient client = new("stun.12voip.com");
        IPEndPoint selfEndpoint = await client.GetForeignIP();
        LaunchPortHolding(client);

        Console.WriteLine($"Your endpoint: {selfEndpoint}");
        Console.Write("Enter companion endpoint:");
        string endpoint_str = Console.ReadLine();
        //endpoint_str validating...
        companion_endpoint = IPEndPoint.Parse(endpoint_str);

        waiter.WaitOne();
    }
}

The code of the ReusableUdpClient class:
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace STUN;
//interuptable udp cllient
public class ReusableUdpClient:UdpClient
{
    readonly UdpClient timer;
    IPEndPoint timer_endpoint;
    CancellationTokenSource timer_starter;
    CancellationTokenSource interupter=new();
    CancellationTokenSource timer_stopper = new();
    public readonly IPEndPoint self_local_endpoint;
    
    bool received_successfully = false;
    readonly ushort timer_port;
    const byte interupt_byte = 42;
 
    public ReusableUdpClient()
    {
        /*I use 1025, not 1024 as the lower bound,
         because if 1024 is dropped for the timer port,
         then the lower limit of the ports to receive the port of the main client
         there will be 1023 ports, and unprivileged processes cannot use less than 1024 ports
         the same is true for the upper bound*/
        timer_port = (ushort)RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(1025,ushort.MaxValue-1);
        timer = new UdpClient(timer_port);
        timer_starter = new();
        timer_endpoint = GetLocalEndpoint(timer_port);
        self_local_endpoint = GetSelfLocalEndpoint();
        //binding main socket with local_endpoint to know, where timer must send cancelation message
        Client.Bind(self_local_endpoint);
        LaunchTimer();
    }
    static IPEndPoint GetLocalEndpoint(int port) => new(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);
    IPEndPoint GetSelfLocalEndpoint()
    {
         /*
          * This code is necessary to generate port, depended from timer_port 
          * and its random would even probability distribution
          */
         int bottom_max = timer_port-1;
         int top_min = timer_port+1;
         double bottom_probability = (double)bottom_max/(ushort.MaxValue-1024);
         double random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks).NextDouble();
         bool isBottom = random<bottom_probability;
         var (bot, top) = isBottom?(1024,bottom_max):(top_min,ushort.MaxValue);
         ushort port = (ushort)RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(bot,top);
         //generating main ip endpoint
         return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,port);
    }
    void ListenTimer(int timeout)
    {
        interupter = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);
        timer_starter.Cancel();
    }
    void LaunchTimer()
    {
        IPEndPoint broadcastIP = new(IPAddress.Broadcast,self_local_endpoint.Port);
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                timer_starter.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne();
                interupter.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne();
                if (!received_successfully)
                {
                    timer.Send(new byte[] { interupt_byte }, broadcastIP);
                    
                }
                timer_starter.Dispose();
                interupter.Dispose();
                timer_starter = new CancellationTokenSource();
                received_successfully = false;
            }
        }, timer_stopper.Token);
    }
    public new int Send(ReadOnlySpan<byte> data,IPEndPoint destination)
    {
        byte[] sending = new byte[data.Length+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            sending[i + 1] = data[i];
        return base.Send(sending, destination);
    }
    private void StopInterupterSuccefully()
    {
        if (!interupter.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            received_successfully = true;
            interupter.Cancel();
        }
    }
    public byte[] Receive(int timeout,ref IPEndPoint? source)
    {
        ListenTimer(timeout);
        byte[] bytes=Receive(ref source);
        StopInterupterSuccefully();
        Console.WriteLine($"Источник: {source}; Получено {bytes.Length} байт");
        if (bytes[0]!=interupt_byte)
        {
            byte[] result = new byte[bytes.Length - 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
                result[i] = bytes[i+1];
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            source = null;
            throw new OperationCanceledException();
        }
    }
    public new void Dispose()
    {
        timer_stopper.Cancel();
        timer_starter.Dispose();
        interupter.Dispose();
        timer.Dispose();
        base.Dispose();
    }
}

STUNClient is a client written by me. I have tested it many times, it gives the correct external address. I checked it manually :)
Please tell me what's the matter...
I expect, that mobile client will be able to send data to server at least. I checked, that my router hasn't symetric NAT, because it gives one public ip-address:port at the moment for other STUN-servers
